# Meaning in a technical standard

Tags: translation, meaning

Trying to understand a technical standard that I have to use but my skills are apparently too weak as I cannot grasp the meaning:

> 固有の特徴は，機能面の特徴又は品質面の特徴として分類することができる。

In the classification of functions/features to be either functional or quality-related but I am not sure whether that would be accurate.

Comment: Can you give us your own translation? (I also don't understand your last sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

Does simplifying it to the following help? 
Ａは、Ｂ面のＡ、または、Ｃ面のＡとして分類する

固有の特徴は，機能面の特徴又は品質面の特徴として分類することができる。
Characteristic features can be divided in terms of function or quality.

That is, the inherent / unique properties of something can be divided / classified into groups based on whether those properties are something that the thing can perform (function), or with respect to quality (lack of defects etc?).

Comment: +1. I feel the author wanted to say 「壊れにくい」「バグがない」「安定して動作する」「デザインが良い」 and so on are 品質面の特徴, while 「～ができる」「新機能は～だ」 are 機能面の特徴.